# Assignment to an empty range?

Tags: python, range

I have this code:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.zeros((len(file_dirs),4097))
for i in range(len(file_dirs)):
    data[i][:] = np.loadtxt(file_dirs[i])
```

The loop seems to produce the same result with this as well:

```
for i in range(len(file_dirs)):
    data[i] = np.loadtxt(file_dirs[i])
```

What is the difference between `data[i]` and `data[i][:]` on the LHS?

Comment: `data[i][:] =` keeps the object at `data[i]` as is and just replaces its contents; `data[i] =` replaces the entire object with a new one. To what extend that makes a different depends on the details…

Answer (score 2):

Slicing and indexing `numpy.ndarray` objects produces a *view* over the same underlying, primitive buffer. They are different Python objects sharing the same buffer. `data[i]` produces a new numpy.ndarray object, that is sliced with a full slice, which simply returns *another* object with a view over the same exact data, which was a view of the original. The item-assignment operator, `container[item] = value`, works in-place (as it does with built-in containers as well, like `list` and `dict`),

```
data[i][:] = np.loadtxt(file_dirs[i])
```

so that same buffer is modified. Hence, that acts equivalently to:

```
data[i] = np.loadtxt(file_dirs[i])
```

But note, this would *not* work the same way with Python `list` objects (and most other mutable objects you'll encounter in Python). A slice of a list produces a new object as well, but it is independent of the original without sharing memory.

```
>>> mylist = list(range(10))
>>> middle_six = mylist[2:-2]
>>> mylist
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> middle_six
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> middle_six[:] = [ -133, 212, 88,  23, 650,  -88]
>>> mylist
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> middle_six
[-133, 212, 88, 23, 650, -88]
```

And now note what happens with `numpy` arrays:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.arange(10)
>>> middle_six = arr[2:-2]
>>> arr
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> middle_six
array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
>>> middle_six[:] = [98, 101, -88, 17, 525, 88]
>>> middle_six
array([ 98, 101, -88,  17, 525,  88])
>>> arr
array([  0,   1,  98, 101, -88,  17, 525,  88,   8,   9])
```

Note, only some operations in numpy produce a view. "Fancy indexing", for example, with a sequence of indices, does not produce a view:

```
>>> arr = np.arange(10)
>>> first_three = arr[[0,1,2]]
>>> arr
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> first_three
array([0, 1, 2])
>>> first_three[:] = [42, 42, 42]
>>> arr
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> first_three
array([42, 42, 42])
>>>
```